# Question regarding the 90/180 days Schengen rule and national (type D) visas

Tags: visas, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

I am a citizen of the Republic of Macedonia.  This summer, I spent 7 days in Croatia and a little bit over 3 months in Switzerland.  I had a Swiss national visa (type D) valid for 3 months, as I performed an internship during that period.  The "little bit over" (just a few days) period I stayed there as a tourist.

In other words, I spent around 10 days as a tourist in the Schengen area, and 3 months on a type D visa.  My question now is: do the days spent on a type D visa count towards the 90/180 days rule?

I would like to travel to the Schengen area soon (as a tourist), but I'm afraid that wouldn't be possible if those 3 months counted toward the 90/180 days rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three months don't count. According to the Schengen borders code:

> Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States.

Source: http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/AUTO/?uri=celex:32016R0399.